# My HTML5 Game based phonegap not support again for admob

Tags: java, android, html, cordova, admob

I already created my first HTML5 Game with phonegap for android. When I add Google Play Service SDK to support admob plugin after that my game cannot start on both my device and emulator.
You can check out what's wrong from my script from MainACtivity.Java like below:

```
   package com.company.mygame;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.LinearLayout;
   import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
   import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
   import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
   import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import org.apache.cordova.*;


    public class DerpOrigamiFish extends CordovaActivity 
    {
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "XXXXXX";
private AdView adView; 


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml

    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

 // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = super.root;
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

  }
@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  if (adView != null) {
    adView.resume();
  }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
  if (adView != null) {
    adView.pause();
  }
  super.onPause();
}

/** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  // Destroy the AdView.
  if (adView != null) {
    adView.destroy();
  }
  super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

If we remove admob script from mainactivity.java my game can run with properly. I hope anyone can help me to solve this problem with quick

**Updated (3/3/2014)**

Its [my logcat pastebin](http://pastebin.com/agEivu0g) contain error messages when running on emulator

Comment: Is it possible that you need to append `this.` to your defined ad variables? example: `adView = new AdView(this);` change to `this.adView = new AdView(this);`

Comment: @William unfortunately "mynamegame" has stopped when testing in emulator.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Still get same error

Comment: So post your logcat. Show us the error causing the app to stop.

Comment: @William My logcat: http://pastebin.com/agEivu0g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logcat quite clearly shows the problem and the solution:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's 
AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within 
the <application> element:     
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

So add this to your AndroidManifest.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```